# Angular compiler.js:2531 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: More than one component matched on this element

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I've seen multiple of topics with the same problem, but I don't have any of reasons from that answers.
I have a common primeng button

```
     <div [hidden]="isHidden||isProgramVisible" id="statusContainer"
       style="text-align:right; position:absolute; overflow:hidden; bottom:40px;left:0px;max-height:60px;height:36px;right:0px;color:white;padding:6px;">

     <p-button [hidden]="isHidden||isProgramVisible" label="Click" (onClick)="levelUp()"></p-button>
  </div>
```

Nothing specific. And I have weird error
[image]

I can not understand where is the conflict. p-button is primeng button module, that is imported only once. Also, the second button component, first is confligting to, is not actually a component, but only a piece of div code. What can it be? It appeared after I migrated from angular 7 to angular 9

Comment: Angular won't transpile components with the same selector. It seems that you imported twice the same component/module.

Comment: I assume that its primeng button, but nop, I checked all imports before.

Comment: Sometimes it happens because you use short and log imports in the same time. Make sure you import always from the `primeng` and not something like `primeng/ui/api/components` (for example) .

Comment: yes, path is 'primeng/button'

Comment: Does anyone have any idea how to fix it/or find the reason why it happens?:D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in auto updating of project by angular. ANgular puts incorrect import path for few primeng components, like dialogs, dropdowns, trees etc.